# How can a single column .apply() be made faster in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, performance

Learned how to run a profiler for a code that needs many iterations in hopes to make the run times for sustainable. Turns out this take up 55-58% of the run time:

```
data['CDA_Factor_Avg'] = data.apply(lambda row : data['CDA_Factor'].loc[ starting_date : row.name ].mean(), axis=1)
```

Resulting in a Pandas dataframe 'data', columns 'CDA_Factor_Avg' and 'CDA_Factor' like:

| CDA_Factor | CDA_Factor_Avg |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2.5 |
| 9 | 4.66 |

Where the mean is only ever taken up to the current cell. The Index is datetime. Does anyone see any better alternatives?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) mean:

```
>>> df["CDA_Factor"].expanding().mean()
0    1.000000
1    2.500000
2    4.666667
Name: CDA_Factor, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Wow, you made it so easy. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You might divide cumsum by number of elements following way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"CDA_Factor":[1,4,9]})
df["CDA_Factor_Avg"] = df["CDA_Factor"].cumsum() / range(1,4)
print(df)
```

gives output

```
   CDA_Factor  CDA_Factor_Avg
0           1        1.000000
1           4        2.500000
2           9        4.666667
```